# Dynamically added font face not working

Tags: javascript, css, font-face

```
fontFaceString = "@font-face {font-family: 'Lobster';font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;src:url('../../fonts/new_fonts/LOBSTER/Lobster-regular.ttf');}";

var newStyle = document.createElement('style');
newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fontFaceString));
document.head.appendChild(newStyle);
```

I have to add multiple fonts dynamically. I am just trying to add one font with above snippet, It's getting added to style tag but not rendering properly.

Comment: Provide an example with jsfiddle or of your actual page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a special function in JS for adding CSS rules called `insertRule()`, first add `<style></style>` (no need to do it from JS) in your `head` tag, then add this code:

```
var sheet = window.document.styleSheets[0];
sheet.insertRule("@font-face {font-family: 'Lobster';font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;src:url('../../fonts/new_fonts/LOBSTER/Lobster-regular.ttf');}", sheet.cssRules.length);
```